# Logitech quickcam pro 9000 Bayer capture with openCV

Tags: c++, opencv, video-capture, video-processing, logitech

I'm trying to capture the raw data of the logitech pro 9000 (eg. the so called Bayer pattern). This can be achieved by using the so called bayer application, that can be found floating over the internet. It should return a 8 bit bayer pattern, but the results are quite obviously not such a pattern.

However; The image that is being streamed seems to be quite off. As can be seen in the image below, I get 2 images of the scene in a 3 channel image (meaning 6 channels in total). Each image is 1/4th of the total capture area, so it would seem that there is some kind of YUV data being streamed.

I was unable to convert this data into anything meaningful using the conversions provided by openCV. Any ideas what kind of data is being sent and (more importantly) how to convert this into RGB?

[image: Cropped example of captured image]

**EDIT**
As requested; the codesnippet that is used to generate the image.

```
system("Bayer.exe 1 8"); //Sets the camera to raw mode
// set up camera
VideoCapture capture(0);
if(!capture.isOpened()){
  waitKey();
  exit(0);
}
Mat capturedFrame;
while(true){
  capture>>capturedFrame;
  imshow("Raw",capturedFrame);
  waitKey(25);
}
```

Comment: Did you try cv::cvtColor with one of those: CV_BayerBG2BGR, CV_BayerGB2BGR, CV_BayerRG2BGR, CV_BayerGR2BGR, CV_BayerBG2RGB, CV_BayerGB2RGB, CV_BayerRG2RGB, CV_BayerGR2RGB

Comment: I believe I did, but it's been a while since I tried. I've not been able to get this code to work, so I abandoned it.

Answer (score 1):

How did you get frames from stream using openCV? Can you share some code snippets? There are too many video formats in openCV for getting correct color channel and compressed data.

I think you should be able to obtain correct image frames as mentioned here :

http://forum.openrobotino.org/archive/index.php/t-295.html?s=c33acb1fb91f5916080f8dfd687598ec

Comment: I've added the code snippet that is used to generate the image. The capturing of "normal" images works perfectly, but I'm looking for the raw data (eg; the Bayer pattern).

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely to happen if the out put data format ( width, height, bit depth, no of channels...) of camera and the data format your program expect is different.

However i could capture of logitec pro cam, simply by using

```
Mat img;
VideoCapture cap(0);
cap >> img;
```

Comment: The problem is not in the actual capture of the logitech. The camera works perfectly fine in the "normal" mode (eg; the full image). However, I want access to the raw data.